# Python XPath returns empty list?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xpath

I am trying to scrape information from [this webpage](https://www.msn.com/en-us/weather/weatheralerts/Beverly%20Hills,California,Unite%20d%20States/we-city?weadegreetype=F&day=1&ocid=ansmsnweather%20'this%20webpage'). 
Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bctKy.png) should the webpage not work.

---

I am trying to print the text in the first `<span>` element.

I copied the XPath as provided by the Inspect Element view in Google Chrome (see screenshot above), and 
`//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/p[1]/span[1]/text()` was copied to my clipboard.

---

This is the code I tried:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

# get alert info
page = requests.get( 'https://www.msn.com/en-us/weather/weatheralerts/Beverly%20Hills,California,Unite%20d%20States/we-city?weadegreetype=F&day=1&ocid=ansmsnweather')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

alertInfo = tree.xpath( '//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/p[1]/span[1]/text()')

print alertInfo
```

---

However, all I got as an output was `[]`. I am sure that the URL string is correct. Why did this occur?

I also tried `alertInfo = tree.xpath( '//span/text()')` to see if I could just pick out the element in the list, but even that returned an empty list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. the problem is not with your xpath but rather with the way naughty msn replies to script requests. you may try to trick it as if you're a rel browser [hence](https://gist.github.com/abloch/6f3cd8a70778e5538a4b062fcad1a493)
2. if all you're looking is weather reports, I strongly advise getting away from parsing html pages (which is highly vulnerable to page structure changes) some services have great API for example accuweather or yahoo! weather

Comment: I tried the code you posted on github, but it still seems to output an empty list.

Comment: please compare the two code's `page.content`s. I believe the header send tricks MSN to provide you with a better page

Comment: How would I compare the `page.content`? Printing it just gives me `<Element html at 0x3062908>`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/rwu8/62cbd3ed04b8c1acd234283ac441e3bf) is the code I used, by the way.